# Fill in null value base on date column condition (pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda, null

Lets say I've four columns

1. Date: datetime
2. Col_1: float
3. Col_2: float
4. Col_3: float

| Date | Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | NaN | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 2022-02-01 | NaN | NaN | 3.0 |
| 2022-03-01 | 3.0 | 5.0 | 4.0 |
| 2022-04-01 | NaN | NaN | 5.0 |

and I want to fill in columns with null values base on the date column where dates less then 2022-03-01 gets fill with a 0.

Result wanted:

| Date | Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 2022-02-01 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 3.0 |
| 2022-03-01 | 3.0 | 5.0 | 4.0 |
| 2022-04-01 | NaN | NaN | 5.0 |

My Code:

```
null_column = [x for x in list(df.columns) if df[x].isnull().sum()>0]
for c in null_column:
    df[c] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if (np.isnan(df[c])) & (df['Date']<'2022-03-01') else x)
```

but I'm getting "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to iterate over Dataframes, it's basically never the best method, and throws out the point of using a Dataframe. Try to find the appropriate Vectorized `pandas` function for whatever it is you're trying to do, it probably exists.

```
mask = df.Date.lt('2022-03-01')
df.loc[mask] = df.loc[mask].fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        Date  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
0 2022-01-01    0.0    1.0    2.0
1 2022-02-01    0.0    0.0    3.0
2 2022-03-01    3.0    5.0    4.0
3 2022-04-01    NaN    NaN    5.0
```

---

To modify a single column:

```
mask = df.Date.lt('2022-03-01')
df.loc[mask, 'Col_1'] = df.loc[mask, 'Col_1'].fillna(0)

# Output:
        Date  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
0 2022-01-01    0.0    1.0    2.0
1 2022-02-01    0.0    NaN    3.0
2 2022-03-01    3.0    5.0    4.0
3 2022-04-01    NaN    NaN    5.0
```

---

You may consider making `Date` a datetime index if they're unique:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
# This simplifies indexing with Dates:
print(df.loc[:'2022-03-01'])

# Output:
            Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
Date
2022-01-01    0.0    1.0    2.0
2022-02-01    0.0    NaN    3.0
2022-03-01    3.0    5.0    4.0
```

Comment: what if I want the reference date to be dynamic example col_1<2022-03-01, col_2 <2022-02-01 and col_3 < 2022-04-01? would it be the same except I create a mask list and loop through it?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: For the dynamic form probably loop over the columns with np.where

Comment: @BeRT2me dynamic as in depending on the column being filled the date condition changes.

Comment: `np.where` or `df.where` would both be another way of doing this~

Comment: Yes, I'd probably work on each column individually, making a loop of sorts there would be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like using lambda is not the best of ways to handle pandas dataframes